# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Problems Booting

Tags: boot

After I installed **rar(4.2.0-1)** which allows archive manager to open rar files. I then removed the program because I noticed when I powered off my computer and powered it back on the power goes on but it does not load up bios. I have to unplug the power chord.

When I plug the power chord back in the computer boots up. If I shut down after using computer and do a cold boot within 5 minutes it will boot up. If I wait longer than 5 minutes the machine will not load bios. it was all working fine until the rar program was installed. I still have rar files that will open in archive manager even after removing program.

This install was recommended by the ubuntu operating system when attempting to open .rar file.

Comment: It's next to impossible that the installation of the RAR program had any effect on the system BIOS whatsoever. This is likely a hardware/firmware issue and most definitely unrelated to Ubuntu. [SU] would be a better fit for your issue.

Comment: Well maybe it was not software related however everything was working perfectly. My lithium wafer battery seems to be ok however I did see the sytem time was incorrect in the bios.  I have not flashed or done any changes to the bios of this motherboard so something caused this change to happen and it was not a user error.

Comment: I removed the lithium wafer battery. Reinstalled it and booted and the bios gave me the answer. Low battery voltage. I will install a new battery and let you know how this pans out. Clue was system clock.... not keeping proper time.

Answer (score 0):

Bios not was not loading due to a weak lithium wafer battery. The battery was last changed in 2003. I installed a new battery in the motherboard and the machine boots up the bios and OS. All is OK with the PC and Linux is performing well. Dell Dimension C521. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.